# Fill a form in excel with data from sql, SSIS or SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel-2007

We have been provided a form, layed out in Excel, that needs to be filled in based on data we have sitting in our SQL database.

I'm trying to determine the best way to electronically fill the form in. I could create an SSRS report, and lay it out as close as possible to the form provided, but I was wondering if I could use the excel file as a template in SSIS and have SSIS fill in the various fields.

It is not a simple table spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use an SSIS package, connect to your DB and do the transformations on the package itself, there are several components, I'm pretty sure you will be able to deal with all the situations.
You could use the report and save it as excel but I think will be more complicated. 
One thing to consider is that SSRS has limitations when exporting to excel. There is a limit of 60k rows. If you try to export more you will get:

Excel Rendering Extension: Number of rows exceeds the maximum possible rows per sheet in this format; Rows Requested: 209048, Max Rows: 65536

There is a work around to this but its time consuming.

This is an excel 2003 limitation and SSRS 2008 cannot export to excel 2007

Comment: Trying to map my data to the excel Destination. Data needs to go into cell AH25, AP25, AH27, etc... not sure the best course at this point. Any samples?